# Twilio Voice not working in Video Call

Tags: swift, twilio, swift4

Hi i am using Twilio Video sdk to implement a video calling feature inside my app. I implemented the video call successfully and the video is successful. But the voice is not transmitting between the two users.
I added MicroPhone Usage Key too in the info.plist file but that did not solve the problem. I tried with and without the microphones and headset but no voice.

I see that the `addedVideoTrack` functions is being called and the statements are printed inside that function. But the function `addedAudioTrack` is not being called at all.

Can some body provide a solution for this problem or point me in the right direction. 
I am using the code from Quicstart example provided by Twilio.
Here is the link to the [tutorial](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift/tree/master/VideoQuickStart) i am referring to.

Comment: Did you give permission for the app to use your microphone? Have you changed anything from the quickstart or are you running the code as is?

Comment: Yes, i did change and it was my mistake. I actually commented a line that prepared audio to work. I just found out and it worked. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Ah, good news that you fixed it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out a line and it was my mistake. I actually commented a line that prepared audio to work. I just found out and it worked. But now the video and audio are fully functional.

Comment: can you share that line after that it stated workig